# unable to add outfile prepared statement mysql

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

This is my query:

```
SET @query2 = CONCAT('
    SELECT * FROM table_name 
    INTO OUTFILE "',arg_file_path,'/',@var_table_name,'_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.csv" fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by ''"'' lines terminated by "\n"    ');
```

But it produces following output:

```
SELECT * FROM lcs_tbl_test
            INTO OUTFILE "/data/test_outfile/lcs_tbl_test_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.csv" fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by "
```

"

Basically I want "\n" to print as it is in my prepared statement. It is executing \n as line separator in current code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use back slash as double means for '\' you need to use '\'. Please use below statement.

```
SET @query2 = CONCAT('
    SELECT * FROM table_name 
    INTO OUTFILE "',arg_file_path,'/',@var_table_name,'_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.csv" fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by ''"'' lines terminated by "\\n"    ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` as extra escape character to not interpret `\n` as new line character.

And, you may also require to change `current_timestamp` string from literal to dynamic value. Change your `concat` parameters as below:

```
SET @query2 = CONCAT(
    'SELECT * FROM table_name INTO OUTFILE "', 
    arg_file_path, '/', @var_table_name, '_', ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 0 ), '.csv" 
    fields terminated by "," 
    optionally enclosed by ''"'' 
    lines terminated by "\\n"    ');
```

It produces output as:

```
SELECT * FROM lcs_tbl_test
INTO OUTFILE "/data/test_outfile/lcs_tbl_test_20140410132736.csv" 
fields terminated by "," 
optionally enclosed by '"' 
lines terminated by "\n"
```